# how to modify a specific object at a index using spread operator in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, spread-syntax

I want to use spread operator. Scenario is that there are no of players (displayed as player tile on UI). Whenever I am clicking on any of player-tile, it is becoming active (getting highlighted). Condition is that at a time only one player should be highlighted. So, when a player-tile is clicked its attribute `ifActive: true`, and rest of players attribute `ifActive: false`
The `playerReducer` is getting clicked player-id as `action.payload` (`action.payload` is giving the id of player which is currently clicked). Now I have to modify my `state` without mutating it. I have to use spread operator for it. how to modify a specific object at a index using spread operator?

```
const initialPlayerState = {
  tabs: [
    { id: 1, name: 'player 1', ifActive: false },
    { id: 2, name: 'player 2', ifActive: false },
    { id: 3, name: 'player 3', ifActive: false },
  ]
} 
const playerReducer = (state = initialPlayerState , action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_PLAYER:
          //how to modify state using spread operator, and how to modify 
          //a specific object at a specific index.  
          return { ...state, /*some code hrere*/};
        default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

> how to modify a specific object at a index using spread operator? Strictly, I have to use spread operator and each player should have `ifActive` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return { ...state, players: state.players.map(player => ({ ...player, selected: player.id === action.id })) };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update one of the `players`, for example `ifActive` flag, and recreate the `tabs` array to trigger re-render of tabs component, you can do it like this

```
    const initialPlayerState = {
      tabs: [
        { id: 1, name: 'player 1', ifActive: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'player 2', ifActive: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'player 3', ifActive: false },
      ]
    } 
    const playerReducer = (state = initialPlayerState , action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case SELECT_PLAYER:
              return { 
                ...state, // If you have something else in your state
                tabs: tabs.map(player => player.ifActive || player.id === action.id ? {
                  ...player,
                  ifActive: player.id === action.id
                } : player)
              };
            default:
              return state;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong because you're mutating `tabs` by using splice and `tabs` is part of the old state which needs to be immutable. You should use `slice`, not `splice`.

Comment: This is also wrong because you're failing to unset the previous `ifActive`.

Comment: Good catch with `splice`, my bad, thanks. And you are right with incorrect update of `ifActive` flag.

Comment: @DDS 
Well, Because I'm very new to React-Redux I'm little not sure what you mean to say. Could you please tell me in detail what has to be done. 
It will be great help.